# 'com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: PDF header signature not found' when reading the input stream from servlet

Tags: java, itext

I am creating a editable pdf from a servlet. The user enters data and clicks the submit button. The action for the submit button is defined as "button.setAction(PdfAction.createSubmitForm("/fdf", null, PdfAction.SUBMIT_XFDF))".

When I try to read the form fields back into the server using 
FdfReader  reader = new FdfReader (request.getInputStream()), I keep getting the above error of 'PDF header signature not found'. 
On debugging where the error is, the pdf generated has the '%PDF-'. But somehow when the inputstream is being read, I get this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you submit the data as XFDF (which is the XML version of FDF). However, you try reading this data using `FdfReader` instead of `XfdfReader`. `FdfReader` expects a file that is written in PDF syntax and that starts with `%PDF-1`. You are receiving a file that is written in XML and that starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
```

As `<?xml` is quite different from `%PDF-1` (which is the *PDF header signature*), you shouldn't be surprised by the error. It says exactly what is wrong with the data you're feeding to `FdfReader`.

Replace `FdfReader` with `XfdfReader` in your code and your problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing this out. Yes, the server side error on 'header signature' does not appear anymore. But the adobe reader on the client side still pops up the error dialog "An error occurred during the submit process. Cannot process content of type". I thought this was due to the server side error. But this dialog still shows up even though there is no server side error. I am using Adobe Reader XI. Please let me know.  Also I really want to appreciate your amazingly simple to use PDF API, this is great work.

Comment: What does your server-side code send to the browser? My guess: I think that you're sending HTML which can't be processed by a PDF viewer. You should either return a PDF file or nothing (response code 204: No content).